# Change the data type of a WPF TreeView ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I want to change the data type of the binding of a `TreeView` during a button click to another type.

This is the code declaration of the `TreeView`. I want to change the type of roles from `StudentRoles` to `BursarRoles`. For example:

```
<local:StudentRoles x:Key="MyData" />
```

to

```
<local:BursarRoles x:Key="MyData" />
```

`TreeView` definition:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:StudentRoles x:Key="MyData" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LevelFour">
        <Border CornerRadius="5" >
            <StackPanel Opacity=" 3">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                       Margin="5 5"
               FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}"
               FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeMedium}"
               Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundVeryDarkBrush}"
               />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="LevelThree"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding SubRoles}"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LevelFour}"
                              >
        <StackPanel Margin="0 3">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                   Margin="2"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundVeryDarkBrush}"
                   FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}"
                   FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeMedium}"
                   />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="LevelTwo"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Roles}"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LevelThree}"
                              >
        <StackPanel Margin="0 3">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RoleDescription}"
                   Margin="2"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundVeryDarkBrush}"
                   FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}"
                   FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeLarge}"
                   />


        </StackPanel>

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="LevelOne"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding UserRoles}"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LevelTwo}"
                              >
        <StackPanel Margin="0 3">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UserDescription}"
                   Margin="2"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource WordOrangeBrush}"
                   FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}"
                   FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeXLarge}"
                   />
        </StackPanel>

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="CanScrolGrid">
    <TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LevelOne}" 
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyData}" 
              Background="{StaticResource ForegroundLightBrush}"
                 />

    <Button Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Width="170"
            Background="{StaticResource WordBlueBrush}" 
            Content="Change Roles" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

The code behind of the `UserControl` sets the `DataContext` of the control to a list of roles, e.g `StudentRoles` in this case:

```
 public partial class RoleControls : UserControl
{
    public RoleControls()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new StudentRoles();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

The roles work fine individually, but I want to be able to change the data context to different roles at runtime. But I can't do so easily because of this line:

```
<local:StudentRoles x:Key="MyData" />
```

How can I replace this line with a line that will allow changes to the `DataContext`?

Here is sample list of roles (`StudentRoles`):

```
/// <summary>
///  The roles a student can perform on the system
/// </summary>

public class StudentRoles : BaseRole
{
    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public StudentRoles()
    {    
        RoleType roleType;
        Role role;
        Role subRole;
        UserType userRoles = new UserType("Student");

        #region Student Management 

        roleType = new RoleType("Stock Management");

        // Register product
        role = new Role("Register Product");
        // Single
        subRole = new Role("Single");
        role.SubRoles.Add(subRole);
        // Multiple
        subRole = new Role("Multiple");
        role.SubRoles.Add(subRole);

        roleType.Roles.Add(role);

        // Update product Status
        role = new Role("Update Product Details");
        // Single
        subRole = new Role("Single");
        role.SubRoles.Add(subRole);
        // Multiple
        subRole = new Role("Multiple");
        role.SubRoles.Add(subRole);

        roleType.Roles.Add(role);

        // View Product
        role = new Role("View Product Details");
        // Single
        subRole = new Role("Single");
        role.SubRoles.Add(subRole);
        // by Brand
        subRole = new Role("By Brand");
        role.SubRoles.Add(subRole);

        // bY level
        subRole = new Role("By Price");
        role.SubRoles.Add(subRole);

        // by business Year
        subRole = new Role("By Business Year");
        role.SubRoles.Add(subRole);

        // Dismiss product
        role = new Role("Delete Product");
        // Single
        subRole = new Role("Single");
        role.SubRoles.Add(subRole);
        // Multiple
        subRole = new Role("Multiple");
        role.SubRoles.Add(subRole);

        // Add the role the list of role type
        roleType.Roles.Add(role);

        userRoles.UserRoles.Add(roleType);

        this.Add(userRoles);

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, it appears that you are setting the `DataContext` but then never actually making use of it.

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to know for sure what would work or be best in your scenario. However, from what you've shared so far, it appears that the line you are concerned about should just be removed. I.e. don't declare either a `StudentRoles` or `BursarRoles` object, and set the `DataContext` appropriately according to your current state and user input (i.e. to either a `StudentRoles` object as you're doing now or a `BursarRoles` object on the button click).

Of course, the `ItemsSource` will need to be set differently in that case. If the `DataContext` holds the `StudentRoles` or `BursarRoles` object you want to be used in the `TreeView` element, you can just use `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`. E.g.:

```
<TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LevelOne}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          Background="{StaticResource ForegroundLightBrush}"/>
```

Even better would be for you to create a top-level view model for the view, with a `BaseRole` property that can be set as needed. Then, the `ItemsSource` would be initialized from that, e.g. `ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentRoles}"`, where `CurrentRoles` is the property in the top-level view model that you set as needed.

Done that way, then the top-level view model can even have an `ICommand` property that has a command object that handles the button (i.e. bound to the button's `Command` property), where the command target method changes the `CurrentRoles` property.